# Why are <ol> and <dl> not deprecated?

Tags: html, css, list, deprecated, semantic-markup

I was in a situation recently where I was stuck using `<ul>` for HTML lists, but what I really wanted was `<ol>`. I was racking my brain trying to set up a variable to allow me to change it on the fly if I wanted. Then it dawned on me, I could just use CSS `ul.class {list-style-type: decimal;}`. This would get me exactly what I was looking for.

But then I thought, why do we even have `<ol>` any more? Shouldn't it be deprecated? Isn't the list type a distinct style choice, therefore, belonging in a style sheet? At least, this was always the explanation for why you can't copy and paste the list bullets from an HTML page. And then I further wondered about `<dl>`. Yes, it's a slight bit more convenient, but you can easily make the same effects with nested `<div>`, `<p>`, `<ul>`, or `<span>`.

[In this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527446/whats-the-dl-tag-for), it seems that one could argue there's a semantic quality to `<ol>` and `<dl>`. I can buy that, especially for `<dl>`, but it flies in the face of being constantly told that list types are style, not content. Is there more to this that I'm not seeing for why they haven't been deprecated yet?

Comment: Taking that argument to an extreme, all we need really is `div` with a ton of custom classes and mile-long style sheets…

Comment: @deceze And the other extreme is that we do away with style sheets altogether. What's your point?

Comment: Something it doesn't look like you've considered is accessibility - don't forget not everyone takes in content the same way as you and those with screen readers rely on the semantic meanings of tags.

Comment: @skyline3000 Screen readers recognize the list-style-type attribute and announce the list markers accordingly. I don't know if they solely depend that though.

Comment: For that matter, why keep ul? List styles can be applied to *any* element with display: list-item, so you could theoretically recreate the effect using just divs, just as you say can be done with the dl element. @deceze's original point isn't as extreme as it sounds - even if he describes it that way.

Answer (score 10):

The difference between ul, ol and dl isn't only in the way these elements look like when rendered. There is a huge semantic difference. That's why they can't be just deprecated in favor of a ul.

> I could just use CSS ul.class {list-style-type: decimal;}. This would
>   get me exactly what I was looking for.

See, this is what you get wrong. You wouldn't get exactly the same result. If you use ol or dl only because how they look, you're doing it wrong.

> Isn't the list type a distinct style choice

Definitely not. When you use a html tag, you should know why exactly you did that. All 3 types of list have its own meaning and use.

**ul** = unordered list. The **order of the elements does not matter at all**.
A basic example is a shopping list. You don't care what you buy first, you just want to buy all the items on the list.

**ol** = ordered list. The **order is very specific** and it does matter what comes first. A good example is a recipe for a cake. You can't bake it first and then add ingredients.

**dl** = description list. You usually use this to a enclose **key-value pairs**, as it encloses a list of pairs of terms and their definitions.

Sure, when it comes to how these lists look, you can swap one for another and just apply css rules. Or even use couple of div/span tags and create it from a scratch.
However, when it comes to semantic markup, the difference is huge as I've explained.

Tags in HTML aren't there only to wrap the content, but they carry a meaning as well. They describe what kind of content we're dealing with. It's important for example when you care about SEO.

Stylesheets are there ONLY to change the way how the elements look like in the browser, but they are useless when it comes to explaining the content. Web crawlers for instance don't care about css at all.

Comment: Maybe you could expand on your thoughts. This is kind of a half answer.

Comment: So you would say the reason, possible the only reason, is semantic?

Comment: @fredsbend, yes. Because these lists are about different things, you can't use one instead of the other. You can change how it looks like, but the meaning of the tag will remain the same. If you need ul to look like ol, you probably should use ol immediately.

Comment: *"Web crawlers for instance don't care about css at all."* – Meeeh… Google does; more and more. Good answer anyway.

Comment: @deceze, Google is starting to use css to determine the meaning of elements/content? I admit, as I'm not primarily a front-end developer, I may be mistaken when it comes to this.

Comment: I'm not sure to what degree they do that, but they are evaluating CSS more and more; for instance to detect `display: none` blocks, and even to determine mobile-friendliness. Whether they evaluate list-styles in particular I don't know.

Comment: Whether they evaluate list styles or not doesn't matter, @deceze. A ul is a ul and an ol is an ol. I don't know why CSS was brought into the picture to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

> it flies in the face of being constantly told that list types are style, not content

Who says that? HTML markup is **semantic**, it conveys *meaning*. Always imagine you are parsing your HTML without the context of a style sheet; say because you're a search engine or because you're mining data. Then the semantic difference between `ol`, `ul` and `dl` is pretty clear and significant.

Comment: I agree. A website should still be reasonably usable even with no CSS at all.

Comment: I didn't say HTML markup is not semantic. You quoted what I actually said, and if you read earlier in the post, it's what I've been told as the reason for not being able to copy and paste the bullets while viewing an HTML page. I think you're fixating on something and not really answering the question.

Comment: @fredsbend Copy-and-pasting is a client-side implementation thing, it has nothing to do with what HTML is supposed to do. There's absolutely no reason to be fundamentally unable to copy and paste lists; it just requires your operating system's clipboard and both the originating and targeted application to support list markup appropriately. FWIW, works just fine on OS X: http://imgur.com/a/j1ADg

Comment: @deceze We all know not all browsers do the same things. I'm pretty sure the point of HTML is to make content viewable in a user-friendly or readable way. I think there's a case to be made that that may or may not include copy and paste. Hence, different browser responses when you select a list while viewing a webpage.

Comment: @fredsbend You seem to be making my point for me...!? Quite honestly, I have no idea what differences there are between your point and mine, but quite obviously we're not on the same page.

Comment: @deceze You said `Copy-and-pasting is a client-side implementation thing, it has nothing to do with what HTML is supposed to do.` I disagree. I think a good case can be made that copy and paste is an important part of usability. [Consider CSS tricks' article on it.](https://css-tricks.com/copy-paste-the-web/)

Comment: @fredsbend Err, yes, sure. But if the browser/clipboard/target simply does not support list styles, or whatever else, there's nothing you as a website author can do to shim that behaviour. Also, the article you link to basically says that *the more non-standard markup and crap you add via CSS/Javascript, the more unpredictable the copy-paste behaviour will be.*

Answer (score 1):

The type of list markers is not necessarily just a style choice. An author might want to reference a list item in an ordered list with "See step F.". If this list marker style (`upper-alpha`) is only defined in the stylesheet, it would fail for user agents that have no CSS support or for users that use their own stylesheet. That’s why [`ol`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) has a [`type` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#attr-ol-type)¹.

But ignoring this, there is a *semantic* difference between `ol` and `ul`, not just a presentational difference. If you want to convey that a list is (un)ordered, you *have* to do this on the HTML level². The list marker style has nothing to do with this; you could have an ordered list with bullet points.

For `dl`: You can’t convey the semantics of `dt`/`dd` groups with `div`/`p`/`ul`/`span` elements³, or any other HTML elements (except `table`, to some extent). A name-value group can have one or more names (`dt`) and one or more values (`dd`), which [represent alternatives (!)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722440/1591669).

---

¹ N.B.: It’s [under discussion](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/341) what will happen with `type` in HTML 5.1/5.2.

² It could as well be an attribute for a (fictive) `list` element (`<list ordered>`, `<list unordered>`) or whatever, as long as it’s part of the HTML. So you woul just replace (`ul`)/`ol` with some other HTML element/attribute.

³ Other existing HTML elements could be re-defined to convey this meaning, sure. But, again, this has to happen on the HTML level. So you would just replace `dl` with some other HTML element/attribute.