# How many dt elements allowed in a name, value pair

Tags: html

Can someone explain what this sentence means?

> Within a single dl element, there should not be more than one dt element for each name.
> [image]

I assumed this meant that in a name, value pair (dt, dd pair) located within a dl there can only be one dt. But then the html spec's examples use multiple dt in their name, value pairs.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You will get the answer here. Refer this link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527446/whats-the-dl-tag-for#:~:text=Within%20a%20single%20dl%20element,you%20just%20used%20nested%20lists.)

Comment: @Himani Thanks for your answer, though the link you provided doesn't specifically answer my question in my OP, which is what the specific sentence in the html spec 'Within a single dl element, there should not be more than one dt element for each name.' means, but instead explains what dl, dd and dt are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means - don't use the same *name* more than once in a dl. i.e. Don't do this:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Donald Trump</dt>
  <dd>A former US president</dd>
  <dt>Donald Trump</dt>
  <dd>A businessman</dd>
<dl>
```